# chartjs how to update dynamically data from database(Chartjs cant get the data)

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, chart.js

I am so much new to chartjs and doing this current project with laravel. Now, I need to create a chart which needs to update automatically with no refresh and the data comes from mysql database.I found this kind of code online: https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqaGRR . I tried doing this code and the output always fails me.

```
   // used for example purposes
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// create initial empty chart
var ctx_live = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: readingID,
    datasets: [{
      data: moist,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor:'#00c0ef',
      label: 'liveCount',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js - Dynamically Update Chart Via Ajax Requests",
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

// this post id drives the example data
var readingID = [];
var moist = [];

// logic to get new data
var getData = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/soildata",
    type:"GET",
    success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);


      // process your data to pull out what you plan to use to update the chart
      // e.g. new label and a new data point

      // add new label and data point to chart's underlying data structures
      myChart.data.labels.push("ReadingID " + readingID++);
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(getRandomIntInclusive(1, 25)); <<<<<-----------I DONT KNOW HOW TO PLAY ON THIS PART I GUESS THIS PART CAN MAKE MY DATABASE WORKING

      // re-render the chart
      myChart.update();
    }
  });
};

// get new data every 3 seconds
setInterval(getData, 3000);
```

I guess I need to make something on this function so that my data coming from my database will work properly:
 Chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(getRandomIntInclusive(1, 25));

Anyone?..does anyone know about this?..I am a newbie on chartjs and truely I spent weeks in solving but I guess I cant.I hope someone out there could be a help, even a different code that will solve my problem is highly accepted. Thank you for any actions that will be taken..

Comment: where is the php/mysql for this? You did use those tags after all.

Comment: sorry for that, I deleted it..I just thought someone might know about it since php will be used in the connection process(I did not include it anymore because there were no problem about the connection).. @Fred did you encounter something like this?

Comment: actually, I can't be of much help for this. I deal mostly with php and mysql.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its okey thank you for having the time to read..

Comment: @ℊααnd it outputs the data from my db

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you get back from that ajax call is good, you should be fine with just replacing the

```
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(getRandomIntInclusive(1, 25));
```

with

```
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data);
```

Of course this is dependent on the format of that data when it gets back to you.

I recommend console.log-ing that data once it gets back from the ajax to make sure it's in a format suitable for chartjs

Comment: thank you for your response I tried replacing that line but, what happens is that reading ID is only moving thus, its readingID does not came from my database /soildata ..I just cant get the data from the database.. :'(

Comment: Do you have any backend code in this solution? I.e. Any c#? That is what I have used and using aspnet mvc you can do some pretty nifty things with entity framework to get data from a database. I would suggest looking in that direction!

Comment: I am only using ajax and javascript with chartjs and then php for the database connection. Are you saying that this is not possible with chartjs??

Comment: To be honest I am uncertain. I haven't ever worked with php. I doubt the issue here is with chartjs, just getting the data. I would recommend updating your question to reflect the issues you have with getting data from your db connection.

Comment: I understand and thank you for that. I will consider your suggestion and edited the title already. Thank you so much for the concern I really appreciate your kindness..
do you think I can put a loop(that will update the database automatically) on this function?
getRandomIntInclusive(1, 25)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, `moist = [50, 30]` and the content of the JSON response is as follows:

```
data{"id":"1" , "val":"20"}
```

To update `moist` from `[50,30]` to `[1, 20]`:

```js
myChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = data.id;
myChart.data.datasets[1].data[1] = data.val;
myChart.update();
```